# How to clear the `kill-ring`?

Tags: kill-ring

I really like `counsel-yank-pop`. I like it so much that I have changed my keybindings so that `C-y` is bounded to `counsel-yank-pop`. However, after a while the kill-ring tends to become a big mess.

I would like to "clear" it. It is already possible to do so by re-starting Emacs. But, I would like to do it without re-starting Emacs. Is there some way?

Would it be necessary to write a tailor-made function in Elisp and put it my init file to achieve this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um,

```
(setq kill-ring nil)
```

The clue that this should work is that this is the value of `kill-ring` when you start emacs.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to transform it into a function to be a command. But it does not work out. I tried inserting this on my init file: `(defun clear-kill-ring ()
  "Clear the results on the kill ring."
  (interactive "r")
  (setq kill-ring nil))` . Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Drop the `"r"` in the `interactive` form: you aren't trying to do anything to a region.